# What C/C++ compilers are available for VxWorks?

Tags: c++, c, vxworks

I'm new to the VxWorks environment, I'm wondering what C and C++ compilers are available for use with VxWorks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know Tornado VxWorks IDE using gcc toolchain.
Any way i suggest to use the compiler provided by WindRiver (which i believe their version 
of gcc)  to avoid compatibility problems. 
It's probably worth to menation the VxWorks version you having in mind.

I guess gcc version will be depend on VxWorks version and probably on target platform.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know the version of VxWorks yet ;( And yeah, I will probably stick with the WindRiver supplied compiler... modified GCC is good... Do you know which version of GCC?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to be asking Wind River these kinds of very product specific things?

Answer (score 12):

There are two: gcc and diab.  They will be provided with your WindRiver platform (such as "General Purpose Platform 3.6").  The gcc is modified by WindRiver (and/or CodeSourcery) to work with VxWorks.

Now with VxWorks 6.9 there is a third option: Intel C++ compiler (for Intel target architectures only, 32 and 64 bit) -- diab will not target 64-bit

Comment: FYI - Diab was actually purchased by Wind River. I believe the Diab compiler is now referred as the Wind River Compiler and there is also GCC of course.

Comment: Last I checked you still used "TOOL=diab" but this was a few minor versions ago -- 6.5 I think.

Answer (score 2):

[Greenhills](http://www.ghs.com) development tools also supported the VXWorks environment in the past.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the customary Diab ("Wind River Compiler") and GNU, VxWorks 6.9 added Intel C Compiler (ICC), but ICC seems to have been dropped from version 7.

VxWorks version 7 adds LLVM/Clang.

Comment: Are you the [Assignee](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml?page=37#Bruce_Lueckenhoff) for the Iliad-Odyssey Protocol? If you are can you answer https://superuser.com/questions/1506317/what-is-the-iliad-odyssey-protocol?